Ext grid pagingtoolbar appears but does not perform paging
I have a problem with my grid, I added the pagingtoolbar plugin, it is visible but it doesn't allow pagination.
In other system grids I have the same configuration exactly the same and it works perfectly.

Ext.define('SIEM.agents.Grid',{
    extend: 'Ext.grid.Grid',
    xtype: 'siem-agents-grid',
    requires: ['Ext.grid.plugin.PagingToolbar'],
    cls: 'custom-grid',
    bind: {
        store: '{agents}',
    },
    title: 'Agents',
    plugins: {
        pagingtoolbar: true
    },
    items: [{
        xtype: 'toolbar',
        docked: 'top',
        items: [{
                xtype: 'textfield',
                placeholder: 'Search',
                flex: 1
            },{
                xtype: 'button',
                text: 'Refresh',
                ui: 'action',
                margin: '0 0 0 5',
                handler: 'loadMainStore'
            }
        ]
    }],
    columns: [{
        text: 'ID',
        width: 75,
        dataIndex: 'id'
    },{
        text: 'Name',
        flex: 0.5,
        dataIndex: 'name'
    },{
        text: 'IP address',
        flex: 0.5,
        dataIndex: 'ip',
        sortable: false
    },{
        text: 'Group(s)',
        width: 75,
        dataIndex: 'group',
        sortable: false,
        align: 'center',
    },{
        text: 'Operating system',
        flex: 1,
        tpl: '{os.name}',
        sortable: false,
    },{
        text: 'Cluster node',
        width: 100,
        dataIndex: 'node_name',
        sortable: false,
        align: 'center',
    },{
        text: 'Version',
        width: 100,
        dataIndex: 'version',
        align: 'center',
    },{
        text: 'Status',
        width: 120,
        dataIndex: 'status',
        align: 'center',
        renderer: 'rendererStatusgrid'
    },{
        text: 'Actions',
        width: 75,
        sortable: false
    }],
})

viewModel:
Ext.define('SIEM.agents.MainModel',{
    extend: 'Ext.app.ViewModel',
    alias: 'viewmodel.siem-agents-main',
    requires: ['SIEM.model.Agents'],
    stores: {
        agents: {
            model: 'SIEM.model.Agents',
            autoLoad: true,
            pageSize: 9,
            // remoteSort: false
        }
    }
});

model:
Ext.define('SIEM.model.Agents', {
    // extend: 'SIEM.model.Base',
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
    fields: [
        { name: 'id', type: 'string' },
        { name: 'status_code', type: 'string'},
        { name: 'status', type: 'string' },
        { name: 'version', type: 'string' },
        { name: 'name', type: 'string' },
        { name: 'ip', type: 'string' },
        { name: 'mergedSum', type: 'string' },
        { name: 'manager', type: 'string' },
        { name: 'group_config_status', type: 'string' },
        { name: 'group', type: 'auto' },
        { name: 'configSum', type: 'string' },
        { name: 'registerIP', type: 'string' },
        { name: 'lastKeepAlive', type: 'string' },
        { name: 'dateAdd', type: 'date' },
        { name: 'node_name', type: 'string' },
        { name: 'disconnection_time', type: 'date' },
        { name: 'os', type: 'auto' },
    ],
    proxy: {
        type: 'rest',
        // type: 'rest-new-api', 
        url: `${Ext.manifest.apiUrl}/siem/agents`,
        reader: {
            type: 'json',
            rootProperty: 'data.affected_items',
        },
        writer: {
            type: 'json',
        },
    }
});

In other models I only made this change in the type to rest and the pagination worked normally, the rest-new-api type was used before, but it doesn't work but
The backend is configured to receive the parameters correctly.
Thanks in advance

Does the response from your API contains the data in the appropriate format for the paging to work, as detailed here?

be able to resolve it this way:
Ext.define('SIEM.model.Agents', {
    // extend: 'SIEM.model.Base',
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
    fields: [
        { name: 'id', type: 'string' },
        { name: 'status_code', type: 'string'},
        { name: 'status', type: 'string' },
        ... rest of the code
        { name: 'os', type: 'auto' },
    ],
    proxy: {
        type: 'rest',
        url: `${Ext.manifest.apiUrl}/siem/agents`,
        reader: {
            type: 'json',
            rootProperty: 'affected_items',
            totalProperty: 'total_affected_items'  <-- inserting this property
        },
        writer: {
            type: 'json',
        },
    }
});

